# POST for authentication and then GET for information

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl

I'm using an API to get some information, unfortunately this API has a poor documentation. So here's my problem: to access the API I first need to make a POST for authentication (I inform my access token), then I can make some GET request to retrieve the data. If I use Postman extension (for Chrome) it works like a charm, I first POST the authentication URL and then all the other GET requests return the data. However when I do it with CURL the GET request returns that "Authorization has been denied for this request", I always send the authentication POST first and it always returns true (success).

I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, anyway, some code:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->token = 'token';
    $this->ch = curl_init();
}

public function __destruct() {
    curl_close($this->ch);
}

private function connect($url, $fields, $method = 'GET') {

    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url .'?'. http_build_query($fields));

    if($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    }

    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($this->ch);

    return $output;

}

private function authenticate() {

    return $this->connect('Login', array(
        'token' => $this->token
    ), 'POST');

}

public function execute($url, $fields, $method = 'GET') {
    $this->authenticate();      
    return $this->connect($url, $fields, $method);
}
```

The authenticate function always returns true, however the execute function returns 401.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I didn't realize that in the first POST a cookie was created, and that was the problem. To solve it I added to the connect function these lines:

```
$tmp_fname = tempnam("./","COOKIE");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmp_fname);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmp_fname);
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($method == "GET"){
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url .'?'. http_build_query($fields));
    // This is by default GET request,
    // so do you don't need to use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST anymore
}
else{
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
}
```